# run few viber bots on flask server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere, viber

i made viber bot on python. its working fine. now i am trying to run few bots on one webserver. the first bot is working but 
 the second one not.

```
app = Flask(__name__)  


app2 = Flask('app2')
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def incoming():
    viber_request = viber.parse_request(request.get_data())
    if isinstance(viber_request, ViberMessageRequest):
         viber.send_messages(viber_request.sender.id,[TextMessage(text='test1')] )

@app2.route('/ff', methods=['POST'])
def incoming2():
    viber_request = viber.parse_request(request.get_data())
    if isinstance(viber_request, ViberMessageRequest):
         viber.send_messages(viber_request.sender.id,[TextMessage(text='test2')] )

def set_webhook(viber):
    viber.unset_webhook()
    time.sleep(1)
    viber.set_webhook('https://myhost.pythonanywhere.com')

def set_webhook2(viber2):
    viber2.unset_webhook()
    time.sleep(1)
    viber2.set_webhook('https://myhost.pythonanywhere.com/ff')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    scheduler.enter(5, 1, set_webhook, (viber,))
    t = threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run)
    t.start()

    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    scheduler.enter(5, 1, set_webhook2, (viber2,))
    t = threading.Thread(target=scheduler.run)
    t.start()


    app.run(host='https://myhost.pythonanywhere.com', port=8443, debug=True)
    app2.run(host='https://myhost.pythonanywhere.com/ff', port=8080, debug=True)
```

first bot responding  with test1  but second one silent.
how to run few bots on one webserver properly ? Both tokens are correct

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason could be that you are using:

```
@app.route('/ff', methods=['POST'])
```

instead of

```
@app2.route('/ff', methods=['POST'])
```

On a different note, you don't have to create 2 different apps.
If you remove last line ( app2.run(host='https://myhost.pythonanywhere.com/ff', port=8080, debug=True) ) from your code then your code will work fine and you can access the first bot at https://myhost.pythonanywhere.com/ on port 8443 and second bot on https://myhost.pythonanywhere.com/ff on port 8443 as well

Comment: no , sorry  i have different decorators  names .just made mistake here in my post. thanks for you reply